# Survey completness problems in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I'm trying to have information about the completness in some survey results exported in to a Excel Format I'm using Google Sheets, as every survey there is questions and subquestions the subquestions have a conditional, Example: 4. How are you today? multiple choise answers: Good, Bad, Prefer not to say, so there we have 3 answer options if we click good there is a conditional and the subquestion will be: Why?. So in my survey there is 8 questions and question 4, 7 and 8 has conditional questions if someone answer "Yes". Now here is my problem to calculate the percentage of completness I used this relation: `number of inputs in the survey/number of expected answers`, But as I mentioned before the conditional affects this **expected answers** this Variable is dynamic depending on the answers from question 4, 7 and 8. So I would like to obtain this Variable for every case, if someone put information will have an ID if we have 20 persons doing the survey we will have 20 ID's. So for every record of answers the number will change depending on the inputs from Question 4, 7 and 8. I have prepared a document in Google sheets will the full aproach that I tried but is still hard to have it right I would like to have some help with this.

[Link to the spreesheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Uov1TIhy3jfqPdJ2gZXVjLENSDELacwtWt0S4ToRbrw/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is an image about it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: so let's focus on Q4... Q4 is divided into 10 parts (Q4[X1] Q4[X2] Q4[X3] Q4[X4] Q4[X5] Q4[X6] Q4[X7] Q4[X8] Q4[X9] Q4[X10]) if any of these parts are filled with YES or NO that's 1 point for whole Q4 or 1 point for every part of Q4 ?? now Q4 has a SUBquestion that is divided also into 10 parts (Q4.1 Q4.2 Q4.3 Q4.4 Q4.5 Q4.6 Q4.7 Q4.8 Q4.9 Q4.10) does every part of SUBquestion count as 1 or does any part of SUBquestion count as 1. also! if SUBquestion is filled does MAINquestion count as 1 ? or the count shift to SUBquestion ?

Comment: 1. if any of these parts are filled with YES or NO that's 1 point for whole Q4(Correct)     2. every part of SUBquestion count as 1 (Correct)                                                                     3. if SUBquestion is filled does MAINquestion count as the sum of MAIN QUESTION and number of SubQuestions. Case of Q4: Answer was Yes, the count will be 11 the 10 parts plus the Main one. If Answer was No the count will be 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if any parts of MAIN or SUB question make a whole MAIN/SUB question count as 1 use:

```
QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:F12),,9^9)
```

[image]

if all parts of MAIN/SUB question count as 1 use regular range:

```
AS2:BB12
```

[image]

change those ranges if I got them wrong:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(""={TRANSPOSE(TRIM({
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:F12),,9^9);   QUERY(TRANSPOSE(G2:X12),,9^9);   QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Y2:AH12),,9^9); 
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(AI2:AR12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(BC2:BD12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(BG2:BH12),,9^9); 
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(BI2:BR12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(BS2:BU12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(BV2:BX12),,9^9); 
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(BY2:CA12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CB2:CD12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CE2:CG12),,9^9); 
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CH2:CJ12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CK2:CM12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CN2:CP12),,9^9); 
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CQ2:CS12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CT2:CV12),,9^9)})), AS2:BB12, BE2:BF12}, 0, 1))
```

---

to sum this up there are 17 queries and 2 regular ranges with 12 columns eg 17+12 = 29:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IF(""={TRANSPOSE(TRIM({
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:F12),,9^9);   QUERY(TRANSPOSE(G2:X12),,9^9);   QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Y2:AH12),,9^9); 
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(AI2:AR12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(BC2:BD12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(BG2:BH12),,9^9); 
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(BI2:BR12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(BS2:BU12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(BV2:BX12),,9^9); 
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(BY2:CA12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CB2:CD12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CE2:CG12),,9^9); 
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CH2:CJ12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CK2:CM12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CN2:CP12),,9^9); 
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CQ2:CS12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CT2:CV12),,9^9)})), AS2:BB12, BE2:BF12}, 0, 1), 
 SEQUENCE(29, 1, 1, 0)))
```

[image]

now to skip SUB question if empty we can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(""=TRANSPOSE(TRIM({
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(AS2:BB12),,9^9)})), 1, 0))
```

[image]

and then:

[image]

again, if you got more to skip add it like:

[image]

---

so the last step is to get the "% completeness":

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IF(""={TRANSPOSE(TRIM({
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:F12),,9^9);   QUERY(TRANSPOSE(G2:X12),,9^9);   QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Y2:AH12),,9^9); 
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(AI2:AR12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(BC2:BD12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(BG2:BH12),,9^9); 
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(BI2:BR12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(BS2:BU12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(BV2:BX12),,9^9); 
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(BY2:CA12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CB2:CD12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CE2:CG12),,9^9); 
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CH2:CJ12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CK2:CM12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CN2:CP12),,9^9); 
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CQ2:CS12),,9^9); QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CT2:CV12),,9^9)})), AS2:BB12, BE2:BF12}, 0, 1), 
 SEQUENCE(29, 1, 1, 0))/(29-IF(""=TRANSPOSE(TRIM({QUERY(TRANSPOSE(AS2:BB12),,9^9)})), 1, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: I forget to add something in the Sheet Cleaned from the document some conditions because it's really good but still missing something. I was thinking some formula like this `=COUNTIF(AI2:AR2,"Yes")>0` Then : `IF(TRUE, 11, 1) Wich should be the count if in Q4 there is a Yes at least for that row. That's a little simpler but is like a diferent approach